# Getting error when Flask gets a POST request and trying to use it as JSON data

Tags: python-3.x, flask, webhooks

I'm trying to get a POST request from a server and I want my server to check if data in JSON equals to hash created by me.

I have tried changing `request.get_json(force=True)` to `request.json()`

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        request_json = request.get_json(force=True)
        byte_key = 'REDACTED'
        hashed_order = request_json['hashed_order']
        message = payment_id.encode()
        verification = hmac.new(byte_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        if verification==payment_id:
            return '', 200
            else:
                return abort(400)
```

Also POST request:

```
POST callback_url | application/x-www-form-urlencoded
{
  id: 'ba57e419-a6c9-41b2-a54c-b870d073d899',
  callback_url: 'REDACTED',
  success_url: 'REDACTED',
  status: 'underpaid',
  price: '250413',
  fee: '0',
  auto_settle: '0',
  address: '2Mz4Sx2fmKpop4Hmi4jEtJhiuDCF9VVu2ds',
  missing_amt: '125366',
  hashed_order: 'c2a3896d4c8bfdcc25bbff0f3f15278fd948b96035f0438372eee9d4898f53b7'
}
```

Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a mismatch between

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and expecting to be able to retrieve JSON from the request. For that to work, the mime type has to be `application/json` (or `application/something+json`)

It's covered in the docs. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/

And if you're curious, https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/src/werkzeug/wrappers/json.py#L72 is where that's enforced. (Flask sits atop Werkzeug, which does much of the heavy lifting.)